# Change Profile2 Profile Type after registration

Tags: users

I am trying to get Profile2 module to work with Simple_FB_Connect but the flow of Simple_FB_Connect requires that the user signs up first and then i need to be able to set the Profile2 user type afterwards.

After returning from FB i want the user to be able to click "Consumer" for example and their Profile gets set. Something like this...

```
function MYMODULE_set_user_type() {
  global $user;
  //dsm($user);
  $uid = $user->uid;

  $type = $_GET['type'];
  if (isset($type)) {
    profile2_load_by_user($uid, $type_name = 'main');
    // Unsure what to put here.
    profile2_save($profile);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible with this module. The [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_fb_connect) advertises a `hook_simple_fb_connect_register_alter()` hook to take action on registration, but looking at the [current 7.1.15 version](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simple_fb_connect/tree/simple_fb_connect.api.php?id=f8ea4e83425fe74b374d7f424b5be0962e4a24c7#n27) & the [7.2.x branch](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/simple_fb_connect/tree/simple_fb_connect.api.php?h=7.x-2.x#n26) reveals only a placeholder hook. You'll have to wait for the maintainer to implement it, or to use another module that allows hooks following FB authentication.